# Search results also show code

Tags: 7, javascript, search

I have created some nodes containing *Javascript* code into body field using *Php filter*. I also have tried by using *Full Html* filter. Now when I search through default drupal search then result list also show *Javascript* code as shown in figure below. But when I visit the node that shows right output rather than *Javascript* code.

**When I use Javascript into Php filter:**

[image]

**When I use Javascript into Full Html filter:**

[image]